# Using Cloud Foundry BOSH Command in script

Tags: bosh-deployer, cf-bosh

I am using BOSH 1.3232.0, and I want to use bosh commands in sh script. below is my script file. but When I execute it I get command not found error.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World...!"
bosh target
```

## Output

```
Hello World...!
test.sh: 3: bosh target: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script have no problem. You need to check if your bosh cli is well installed.